# How do you turn on Pact linting on Emacs?

Tags: pact-lang

I want to be able to write Pact code on Emacs. Is Pact available on Emacs? If so, how can I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

Pact is available on Melpa under the `pact-mode` and `flycheck-pact` packages. You can expose them in your `init.el` or `.emacs` by adding the following statements:

```lisp
(require 'pact-mode)
(require 'flycheck-pact)
```

Or, if you'd like to hook `flycheck` so that it starts on startup, simply add a hook:

```lisp
(require 'pact-mode)
(require 'flycheck-pact)
(add-hook 'pact-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)
```